# Reorder list of numbered items using regular expressions

Tags: regex, ssms

I got this list of items (it's in a sql script) and I would like to reorder it by number :

from this :

```
,user_1
,user_2
,user_3
,name_1
,name_2
,name_3
```

to this

```
,user_1
,name_1
,user_2
,name_2
,user_3
,name_3
```

I use sql server management studio 2008 so I have ability to replace using regex but I don't know if that kind of manipulation is even possible with regular expressions.

Comment: I don't know what else is in your toolbox, but regular expressions don't sound like the right tool for the job.

Comment: AFAIK You cannot sort text using regular expressions

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments It's what I wanted to know but I was unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy paste them in excel, then sort and then copy paste back to ssms.

It's that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a bit more description for this to really make sense. 
Perhaps post the SQL script?
Is this data stored in a single varchar field and this is the reason you are looking for a regex solution?

You can easily parse the comma-seperated values using a regex, but you would need some other function to sort that result and it can fairly quickly get messy to do this in SQL.

In general I would say this problem is better handled outside of the SQL statement - eg. process this in your favorite programming/scripting language after getting the result back from the SQL.

Also this problem indicates a design problem with the database layout, if in any way possible the preferred way to solve this would probably be to restructure it.

Comment: The question is not about sql it's about regular expression (I think I made it clear). I ask is there a way to reorder that list with regular expression. In the best case with sql server management studio but I'm open to use other text editors.

Comment: Hi Arno, if you only allow the use of regular expression then the answer is no - this is to my knowledge not possible. You will have to use some sort function afterwards, probably custom written as it is not a straight forward sort you are looking for - so the answer is that you will need to combine regex with something else. If you know a programming/scripting language this would be a very easy solution.